# How do I link a metamask account redirect to a particular web-page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, solidity, metamask

I am working on a blockchain project, where a user registers his/her blockchain account a particular entity and then logs in with their account.
The problem is that I am unable to link the account to redirect to a particular page to display their data.
How do I do this? 
For the front-end, I am using react and for the back-end, I am using solidity to write all the logic.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting errors/trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/) and set provider to  Metamask current provider, in the page you want to show user data.

As metamask injects web3 by default, you can access it through window variable 
`web3Instance = new Web3(window['web3'].currentProvider);`